# GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings' does not contain a key named 'antialiasing'

Tags: gnome, 21.10

I am running into this issue while running Aviatrix VPN
It was working fine before upgrading to Ubuntu-21.10

```
 ~  Logger is ready. App is on: /usr/bin/AVPNC_bin                                                                                                                              ok | 18:16:22 
Starting AVPNC OS:Linux Version:2.14.14
Set the new role = ui
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

(AVPNC:49342): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings' does not contain a key named 'antialiasing'
```